# Why am I able to access enum constants directly as case labels of a switch statement in another class

Tags: java, oop, enums, switch-statement

Why am I able to access enum constant HOT directly in the code below:

```
enum SPICE_DEGREE {
    MILD, MEDIUM, HOT, SUICIDE;
}
class SwitchingFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SPICE_DEGREE spiceDegree = SPICE_DEGREE.HOT; //Unable to access HOT directly
        switch (spiceDegree) {
            case HOT:   //Able to access HOT directly here
                System.out.println("Have fun!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just the way the language is defined - when case labels are enum values, that means the `switch` expression must be an enum of that type, so specifying the enum type everywhere would be redundant.

From [JLS 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant.

and

> If the type of the switch statement's Expression is an enum type, then every case constant associated with the switch statement must be an enum constant of that type.

Comment: But the switch statement is in a different class.How are we able to access directly enum constants of an enum type from outside the enum?

Comment: @user3678484: Because the type is inferred from the type of the switch expression.

Answer (score 2):

Java infers the type of the expression, provided in the `switch` statement and then allows only valid values for the resolved type to be listed in the `case` blocks.

It would be too verbose if we had to specify the type of the enum constant for each `case`.